# Python using list parameter in pyspark.sql like a macro in sas

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list and want to use in pyspark.sql statement.

```
VLIST=['afhjh', 'aikn5','hsa76']
INC=pyspark.sql("select * from table1 where VIG=$VLIST")
```

I tried to use like a sas statement(using $ instead of &) which failed.
How can I use it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something a bit different :

```py
VLIST = ('afhjh', 'aikn5','hsa76')
INC = pyspark.sql(f"select * from table1 where VIG in {VLIST}")
```

or another way :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

INC = pyspark.table("table1")
INC = INC.where(F.col("VIG").isin(*(F.lit(val) for val in VLIST)))
```